# Cookie Expiration Date (on a custom day) in PHP

Tags: php, date, session, cookies

Well I want to do that Cookie Expires on a custom day, for example, tomorrow (08-16):

```
setcookie("Cookie_name", "Cookie_value", time()+86400);
```

But if I acess to the web (08-17), the cookie will expire on 08-18

How can I do that a cookie expire on a custom day?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `strtotime()` to make a timestamp for the date you want:

```
setcookie("Cookie_name", "Cookie_value", strtotime('2013-08-16'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:-

```
setcookie("Cookie_name", "Cookie_value", (new \DateTime)->modify('tomorrow')->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: this is a much more accurate solution!! accepted solution expires at 6:00:00 PM yesterday of specified date!